# javascript binding not takes the object instead window

Tags: javascript

My way of binding not working. please correct me.

```
const ob = {
  name:'arif',
  getName:() => {
    console.log(this)
    return this.name; 
  }
}
const x = ob.getName.bind(ob);
console.log(x()); //return the global name!!
```

Comment: arrow function do not have this, normal function do

Comment: oh.. agree. how it then handled? what is behind can you give some KT to world?

Comment: you don't need to create a reference of function here, you can simply call it like `ob.getName()` or if you want to create variable, then you need to change function to arrow function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:- Here even without binding your function will be taking this as ob only if you call it directly on object.

Arrow function do not have this, normal function do have

```js
const ob = {
  name:'arif',
  getName: function(){
    console.log(this)
    return this.name; 
  }
}
const x = ob.getName.bind(ob);
console.log(x());
```

Comment: pls check my comment. if possible provide some light on the issue

Answer (score 1):

The Arrow function doesn't have an argument property of its own, the bind will fail with Arrow function.

instead, you can use normal function here:

```
 const ob = {
  name:'arif',
  getName: function() {
    console.log(this)
    return this.name; 
  }
}
const x = ob.getName.bind(ob);
console.log(x()); //returns the object name !!
```